# Split date from a string

Tags: sql

I have a column which consist of a text value along with date separated by a space.

The string will be like

```
Application and Removal 2014-11-13 20:46
```

I want to separate the date value `2014-11-13 20:46` and `Application and Removal` as two columns from the string character.

Currently what i do is

```
CASE WHEN ISDATE(RIGHT(FORMNM,16)) = 1 THEN LEFT(FORMNM, LEN(FORMNM) - 17) ELSE FORMNM END as FORMNM,
    FORMSTAT,
    CASE
        WHEN ISDATE(RIGHT(FORMNM,16)) = 1 THEN RIGHT(FORMNM, 16)
    END AS FormDate
```

I know this not the real way. Is there any alternative way?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: is it always `Application and Removal [Date]` format or are other text values possible?

Comment: Please share the code/query/whatever what you tried to achieve your goal. Please read [ask] in [help] to get help how to improve your question. Requesting code without showing any effort to solve your problem is for a freelancer site, not for a Q&A site.

Comment: and is the date/time always in "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss" format? Please note each dbms has its own unique way of manipulating strings, that is why we must know which dbms you are using.

Comment: Don't store data like that, have separate columns for separate data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *SQL-Server* If string side is static - always = `Application and Removal` you can do It simple with `REPLACE` in following:

```
DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Application and Removal 2014-11-13 20:46'

SELECT REPLACE(@str, 'Application and Removal', '') AS [Date],
       'Application and Removal' AS [Other Column]
```

Or if string is dynamic you can make It in more complex way by using `PATINDEX`

```
DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Application and Removal 2014-11-13 20:46'

SELECT LEFT(@str, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @str) - 1) AS column1,
       RIGHT(@str, LEN(@str) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @str) + 1) AS column2
```

**OUTPUT**

```
column1                     column2
Application and Removal     2014-11-13 20:46
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming a constant **yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi** format of the date/time, here are samples, note how different they are, this is why you always tell us what the dbms is

T-SQL (MS SQL/Sybase)

```
RIGHT([that_string_column],16)
```

Oracle

```
SUBSTR(that_string_column, -16, 16)
```